# Wolfram cdf player does not support parallel computing?

Tags: parallelization, cdf-format

I tested the following.

```
Manipulate[t2 = AbsoluteTiming[ParallelSum[N[k/k!, 20], {k, 20000}]]; dp = Dynamic@Parallel`Developer`KernelStatus[]; Column[{Button["kernel", {CloseKernels[], LaunchKernels[4]}, 
ImageSize -> 80], t2, dp}], AppearanceElements -> None]
```

[image]

But, Here is the output from Internet Explore(wolfram CDF Player):

[image]

Wolfram cdf player does not support parallel computing?

Comment: Don't use CDF, it's a dead-end technology.

Comment: @user5601 you mean CDF browser plugin?